# How to access member variables in nested case classes

Tags: scala, case-class

I have this code:

```
case class L2JsonMapping(myTarget: Option[Int])

case class L1JsonMapping(l1: Option[L2JsonMapping])

case class JsonMapping(l0: Option[L1JsonMapping])
```

Assume that they have been initialized. Now how should I get "myTarget" assigned to "result" in the following function:

```
def function(in: JsonMapping): Int = {
    val result = ?
    ...
}
```

Note that I also need to handle Option situation. Thanks.

Comment: what type should `result` be - `Int` or `Option[Int]`?

Comment: It is Int. If it is Option[Int] I guess the default value should be "None"? @TzachZohar

Comment: If it is `Option[Int]`, you don't need to supply a default (you can simply remove the last line in my answer - it would return `None` if one of the options is empty).

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to supply a **default** value to return in case one of the `Option`s is `None`. Let's assume that default is `0` - if so, you can use:

```
def function(in: JsonMapping): Int = in.l0 // get Option[L1JsonMapping]
  .flatMap(_.l1)       // flatMap to get an Option[L2JsonMapping]
  .flatMap(_.myTarget) // flatMap to get an Option[Int]
  .getOrElse(0)        // get value value or default
```

This uses `Option.flatMap` which you can read about in the [ScalaDocs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/Option.html#flatMap[B](f:A=%3EOption[B]):Option[B]):

> Returns the result of applying [the given function] f to this scala.Option's value if this scala.Option is nonempty. Returns None if this scala.Option is empty.

**NOTE** that this simply *returns* the value of `myTarget` - I'm assuming you're assigning it to `result` just to return `result` immediately - if so, that's redundant.